# Ignore upper case word in toCamelCase()

Tags: java

I am using toCamelCase function on lower case words to create heading. I would like to ignore already upper case words or letters.

Please suggest how can I fix this?

Currently I am using this

```
CommonVariables.toCamelCase("MY_STRING");
```

and these functions below

```
public static String toCamelCase(String s)
    {
        String[] parts = s.split(" ");
        String camelCaseString = "";
        for (String part : parts)
        {
            if(camelCaseString.equals(""))
            {
                camelCaseString = toProperCase(part);
            }
            else
            {
                camelCaseString = camelCaseString+" "+toProperCase(part);
            }
        }
        return camelCaseString;
    }

    public static String toProperCase(String s)
    {
        return s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please post some code and what have you tried to fix the issue.

Comment: CommonVariables.toCamelCase("MY_STRING");

Comment: First check if the word is already entirely uppercase; only if it is not, update it by calling `toCamelCase()`.

Comment: It's still not particularly clear, to me at least. Can you give some sample inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is just to adjust your `toProperCase(String s)` to check if your word is already in uppercase, e.g. like this:

```
public static String toProperCase(String s)
{
    // You might want to check if the string is empty before
    if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0))) {
      return s;
    }
    return s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

This will just return the original string if it already starts with an uppercase letter.

However, there is no need to re-invent the wheel. Apache Commons already has a class called [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize(java.lang.String)) that can do exactly what you need:

```
WordUtils.capitalize("i am FINE") = "I Am FINE"
```

Comment: altering toProperCase(String s) works for me, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Thanks Jan Gassen

Answer (score 0):

You could just change your `toProperCase` function to keep the case of the trailing letters:

```
public static String toProperCase(String s) {
    return s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
}
```

Example:

```
System.out.println(toCamelCase("to camel case with UPPER_CASE word"));
// To Camel Case With UPPER_CASE Word
```

Also, but unrelated to the problem, you can simplify your `toCamelCase` function:

```
public static String toCamelCase(String s) {
    return Stream.of(s.split(" "))
                 .map(w -> toProperCase(w))
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

Finally, note that this is not really "[camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)", but more like "[title case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Title_case)". For proper camel case, you could use `Collectors.joining("")` instead.

Comment: Ignoring trailing letters might not give the correct result for inputs like `cAmel`. However it is also not clear to me if the result should actually be `Camel` or `cAmel`

Comment: @JanGassen Agreed, not matter what case a word is in, it's hard to guess what the correct case should be. Could always be some sort of acronym or styled proper name, like "iMac" or similar.